# User registering/login management in GWT application

Tags: java, gwt

I have a java application with GWT frontend, that do some stuff.

Now I want to implement users and their registrations, things like "forgot password", logging in and out.

My problem is - it is a thing, that almost everyone does at their application, but there are many things to do wrong (hashing passwords, somebody faking "forgot password", and so on), so there has to be some general solution or library.

And what I mean by that is both some GUI widget on client side and something for the server side, that would handle the user logins and save their passwords.

Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ)

It describes several things:

- How to Create a 'login' page that is based on user/password authentication.
- How to Store this data in a secure fashion on your server.
- Allow users to 'remain logged in' for as long as you want so they don't have to 
  enter their user name and password every time.

and much more.

Comment: Thanks.

I have seen that page, I just think it is still too complicated and there are still too much stuff to do wrong there in my opinion.

I know I maybe sound naive :) but I would like more "automagical" solution. Something like Spring Security, only more.... easy to set up.

Comment: If you mention Spring security, why not use it? Build a login page with JSP or even static HTML and send the login request to the spring security servlet j_spring_security_check. All the redirection logic, remember me, etc. can be configured. On success, redirect to your GWT app page. The logout link is a href pointing to Spring's logout servlet again (j_spring_security_logout). On the server side you can work with UserDetailsService to plug-in your user persistence. Though, I'm not aware of a generic approach for forgot password functionality.